# Recover Files from Verizon LG EnV3 (VX9200) Phone?

Tags: forensics, phone, data-recovery

I am running into trouble trying to recover files from my Verizon LG EnV3 VX9200 phone. My computer, running Windows 7, will only read the phone as a Windows Portable Device and will not assign the phone a drive letter. My questions are these:

**1. Is there any way to get this particular phone to show up on my computer with a drive letter? (I've already downloaded drivers and BitPim.)**

**2. Is there any recovery software out there that can read the files off of a Windows Portable Device?**

Any suggestions would be helpful. (I am particularly looking to recover photos and videos.)

Lastly, any additional websites that focus mobile phones (mobile phone forums)?

Comment: better suited for Superuser.com

Comment: Well, this is the right place. Annoyingly, literature on phone forensics is pretty rare, and I've not come across any as a cyberforensics forensics undergrad. The state of the art on phone forensics outside specialised places is.. poking at the phone, sadly enough.

Comment: I figured that might be the case. At least I've given it a more thorough attempt.